# Why does golang do bit "flipping" when the number is negative?

Tags: go

Why does golang do bit "flipping" (1->0 and 0->1) when the number is negative?

I wanted to see how exactly number looks like "raw" in memory so I used unsafe pointers. Also, since my machine is little endian, the least significant byte is at the lowest address (first in print).

Golang code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var x1 int32 = 1240
    ptr1 := unsafe.Pointer(&x1)
    value1 := (*[4]byte)(ptr1)
    fmt.Printf("x1 = 1240 in binary representation: %08b\n", value1)

    var x2 int32 = -1240
    ptr2 := unsafe.Pointer(&x2)
    value2 := (*[4]byte)(ptr2)
    fmt.Printf("x2 = -1240 in binary representation: %08b\n", value2)
}
```

Output:

```
x1 = 1240 in binary representation: &[11011000 00000100 00000000 00000000]
x2 = -1240 in binary representation: &[00101000 11111011 11111111 11111111]
```

I expected the second output to be:

```
x2 = -1240 in binary representation: &[11011000 00000100 0000000 10000000]
```

So, I expected only the sign bit to change (8 bits look from right to left) from **0** to **1**, however, the reversing of all bits is done (all 0 became 1 and vice versa).

Why did this happen?

Thanks in advance to everyone for the answers.

Comment: Look for "2's complement representation"

Comment: this isn't specific to Go, this is how negative integers are represented on most systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: @JimB From the link you gave: "*Two's complement uses the binary digit with the greatest place value as the sign to indicate whether the binary number is positive or negative. When the most significant bit is 1, the number is signed as negative; and when the most significant bit is 0 the number is signed as positive.*". That's literally what I expected, that is, the most significant bit to be 1...

Comment: @LeaBit: that describes only the sign bit, keep reading. Go is not doing anything unique in your example (applying two's compliment directly to `x1` in your example: https://go.dev/play/p/yLgrFELVf5r)

Comment: @JimB Thanks man, I understood it now, just have one question. This is how it will be represented in program memory but what about serialization (for network transport for example) and storing, for example, in bit file. Will it be stored/serialized as I wrote ("11011000 00000100 0000000 10000000") but when It start execution of program it will be converted to "00101000 11111011 11111111 11111111"?

Comment: @BurakSerdar Yes, thanks Burak Serder for the help. Can you just tell me what do you think about this mini-question asked here in comment? :)

Comment: "but what about serialization" The answer depends solely on the exact details of what type of serialization and what transfer technologies are used and cannot be answered. (You also do not need to know; it's complicated on the hardware level.)

Comment: @Volker I just wonder whether is it in context of serialization (not necessary for transfer) and file it stored as I wrote (with most significant bit as 1) or it also uses 2's complement representation? I assume its most significant bit but when start execution its "transformed" in 2's complement representation.

Comment: @LeaBit, that depends on how it is encoded. See `encoding/binary` package docs

Comment: @LeaBit, that is only for binary encodings. "-1" is also a perfectly valid encoding.

Comment: @BurakSerdar By "-1" you mean 2's complement?

Comment: I mean the string "-1", the two characters "-" and "1". How a value is represented in memory is a different thing than how it is encoded on wire, or file.

Comment: @BurakSerdar So, if I understand it, you want to say that it can be serialized however we want. In the way I wrote (with sign bit), the way you suggested (with -1) or as 2's complement and as long as we know how to deserialize it (for example, we know that is a negative number, so whether represented as 2's complement or as I said with a sign bit in some file or on a wire) won't be a problem since they are all the same values. However, when the program is executed negative numbers will always be represented in memory as 2's complement? Did I understand it now correct?

Comment: In theory, no. But I do not know a system that does not use 2's complement to represent integers. The "value" represented by a group of bits depends on how you interpret them, i.e. the type system. The same group of bits can be read as a signed negative number, or an unsigned positive number. There are many technical problems in the way you ask, but at a high level, you are correct.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thank you one more time for wasting your time on helping me. I'm in the process of learning and that's why the questions are little strange. **I mean signed integers (we wouldn't have this problem with unsigned ones).** I understood this "in theory, no" to refer to the fact that it doesn't have to be represented in memory as 2's complement, however in practice it is almost always like that (because as you said, you don't know a system that doesn't use the given representation in memory) . Is that what you meant to say? If they are signed int, Is answer to my question now yes? :)

Comment: If you want to see a representation of numbers that is different (and uses a different way of encoding negative numbers) look up "binary-coded decimal". If you wanna dig deeper (probably far too deep) look up "Ackermann (en)coding" which encodes "any finite thing" (HF actually) as a bitstring and thus encodes also natural and whole numbers (albeit in a way you probably won't recognise and cannot work with).

Comment: In regard to "serialization": You seem to mix up "representation" and "serialization". You represent a number (like uint16, int32 or float64) by some bitpattern. You break this bitpattern into bytes. How you do this bitpattern --> sequence of bytes is called "endianess". This is a hardware thing of how you organize your RAM and your CPU. No "serialization" here. This is just _representation_. When you want to ship such a number from your RAM to somewhere else (file, network, ...) you have to _serialize_ this sequence of bytes in RAM to some (other or the same) sequence of bytes.

Comment: @Volker After doing some research, I realized a few things. The **representation** of "things" (in this case negative numbers) depends on the architecture (hardware - CPU) on which the program is executed and nothing more. If the CPU works with 2's complement according to the Little endian principle, negative numbers will be represented in that way/manner in the RAM memory and in the execution bit file on the disk. On the other hand, **serialization** is the way in which we will present the "things" that we want, for example, to transmit over the wire or write to a file.

Comment: @Volker For that we can for example use JSON where negative numbers will be written as ASCII characters ("-" and "1" for "-1") and that has nothing to do with the form in which the given number (-1) must be represented in binary form when executed on a processor (which is usually 2's complement). In other words, when "-1" is read from that JSON file and translated into "numeric" form for performing arithmetic operations or storing in RAM/hard disk (execution bit file) it will be transformed into 2's complement (because that is the way the architecture - CPU works).

Comment: @Volker We can also serialize in "HEX form" to some file, where we would potentially also have to worry about the endians. For example, the number `1240` can be represented as `000004D8` in the file (Big endian principle) or `D8040000` (Little endian principle). I hope you agree with everything written (and that someone in the future who reads this, along with what you wrote, will help them understand things better). I would like you to correct me if something is not correct.

Comment: _Any_ serialization has to be correct. Endianess is the least thing to worry here.

Comment: @Volker I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "`Any serialization has to be correct.`". Did you want to say that whatever the serialization is, it is correct as long as we can correctly deserialize it. So we can even serialize "-1" as "fds" and as long as we know that it is "-1" everything is fine. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter which bijection you use to serialise: -1 <--> fds; -2 <--> tadata; 0 <--> 9999; 1 <--> -0; etc. It just has to be a bijection; Some are more sensible than others. The more you ask about this the more I think you are chasing a XY problem.